# I am joining three table but i want to use values of one of these tables for other two tables separately

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join, codeigniter-3

I have 3 Tables Questions, Answers and Comments where there are multiple answers to the same question and many comments to a single answer.

I want to show who answered the question and who commented to that answer.

As well i want to show the user who replied and users who commented on the same answer.

So please help me to join the same user table twice in both tables answers and comments.

Table: questions: id, text, user_id(fk)

Table: answers: id, que_id(fk), user_id(fk), text

Table: comments: id, ans_id(fk), user_id(fk), text

Table: users: id, name

```
$this->db->select('answers.id as aid,
                   answers.user_id as auser_id,
                   answers.text as atext,
                   comments.id as cid,
                   comments.user_id as cuser_id,
                   comments.text as ctext,
                   users.id as uid,
                   users.name as uname');
$this->db->from('answers');
$this->db->join('users','answers.user_id = users.id', 'left');
$this->db->join('ans_comments','answers.id = comments.ans_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('users','comments.user_id = users.id', 'left');
$this->db->where('que_id','1');
return $this->db->get();
```

My problem is that:

> I am getting the same user for all comments.
>
> I want different commentator for different comments.

Comment: what is the output and what are is your expectation from the query

Comment: I am getting wrong commentator that is actually who anwered the question.

Comment: You have **TOO MANY UNCLOSED QUESTIONS** and you never approved a right answer and if you keep it like that, no one will answer your questions again.

Comment: @Dharmendravadher my advice to you is to fix that issue and begin to show your gratitude for all the experts who did their best to help you and approve their answers that helped you to fix your problems. and of course to help other developers who may face a similar problem in the future.

Comment: Ohh sorry for that I didnt know that.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to join the same table twice you should use a different name:

**TESTED**

```
$this->db->select('A.id AS A_id,
                   A.uid AS A_uid,
                   A.text AS A_text,
                   C.id AS C_id,
                   C.uid AS C_uid,
                   C.text AS C_text,
                   UA.id AS UA_id,
                   UA.name AS UA_name,
                   UC.id AS UC_id,
                   UC.name AS UC_name');
$this->db->from('answers AS A');
$this->db->join('comments AS C','C.aid = A.id', 'left');
$this->db->join('users AS UA','A.uid = UA.id', 'left');
$this->db->join('users AS UC','C.uid = UC.id', 'left');
$this->db->where('qid', 1);
$query = $this->db->get();

$result = $query->result_array();
```

If you noticed i used a different name for each join and used that name to get the related data, so if you want the user name for the answer you'd use `UA.name`and if you want it for the comment you'd user `UC.name`, and it gives you all the flexibility you need.